# cp non-hidden files only

Tags: shell, cp

Is there a good way to run `cp` on the shell (MinGW, in my case) to copy *only non-hidden files* (i.e. files whose names do not begin with `.`)?

I'd like to exclude my `.svn` folders and their contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell doesn't expand `*` to include names starting with a dot, so:

```
cp * /target/directory
```

That won't copy the `.svn` directory.

If that isn't your issue (e.g. you are trying to do a recursive copy with sub-directories that contain hidden files), please clarify what you are up to.

Comment: +1 for promptness and concision.

Answer (score 1):

ls on its own will only show you non-hidden files. If you replace the `echo $file` command with your cp command that should work.

```
for file in `ls`; do echo $file; done
```

Something like this would work fine:

```
for file in `ls`; do cp $file /path/to/desitination; done
```

There are more complicated ways of doing this, but for your needs this seems suitable enough.

**DISCLAIMER: This does not work if there are spaces in the files names.

A fix would be just using the star wildcard. If you run `echo *` you'll notice that this does not expand to hidden files. Thanks to Jonathan Leffler

Comment: This runs into problems if/when file names contain spaces, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ls to list all the non hidden files and copy it:

```
cp $(ls) destination
```

Comment: This runs into problems if/when file names contain spaces, etc.